# How to Get Asset Volume Name

Tags: assets

Trying to figure out how to get the "name" and "handle" of an asset volume, given the volume ID. Tried all the obvious things, no luck!

Answer (score 2):

The [Volumes service](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-volumes.html) is available via `craft.app.volumes`, so you can do

```
{% set volume = craft.app.volumes.getVolumeByHandle('volumeHandle') %}
{{ volume.name }}
```

or

```
{% set volume = craft.app.volumes.getVolumeById(123) %}
{{ volume.name }}
```

Additionally, if you have an Asset model available, you can get its volume like this:

```
{% set volume = asset.volume %}
{{ volume.name }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
{% set query = craft.assets.volume('volumeHandle').one() %}
{{ query.volume.name }}
```